# Unity disable SteamVR

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, steam

I'm making a game which is playable with VR and without VR. The `SteamVR` plugin is inside my project folders, but no `CameraRig` or other `SteamVR` object is inside my scene.

When I start the game, `SteamVR` starts.

How can I only activate `SteamVR` when I need it? (When it is checked in the settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable VR support in Unity. This will disable SteamVR from starting. This can be done via code by using the `VRSettings` class. Specifically, the [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings-enabled.html) value.

So, if you have two different scenes, the VR scene could set `VRSettings.enabled = true;` and the non-VR scene would use `VRSettings.enabled = false;`

Additionally, you can switch VR platforms by using something like `VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("OpenVR");`.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking in 2019, make sure that `Automatically Enable VR` in `Edit > Preferences > SteamVR` is **off** if you need to build also non-VR scenes

[image]

Comment: This setting does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've found to work is to both uncheck 'Auto Enable VR' on Assets/SteamVR_Resources/Resources/SteamVR_Settings.asset and also uncheck Virtual Reality Supported on the Player Settings.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a **CameraRig** object for your SteamVR or a normal **Character controller** for your Normal game mode (non-VR mode). You only require the on/off these two game-objects and need to on one game-object at a time. [[more]](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/both-oculus-and-normal-game-2-in-1.292252/)

Answer (score 2):

For those looking in 2018, here is the solution for 2018.2.6f1

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.XR;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        XRSettings.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this ever worked it not longer does.

Answer (score 2):

Solved

First go to 
Assets/SteamVR_Resources/Resources/SteamVR_Settings.asset

disable auto enable VR

then go to project settings, Player, XR Settings and disable VR Support

Answer (score 1):

None of these suggestions work in December 2019.

The only fix I found is that you have two cameras in two different game objects, one for VR and one for non VR. Inside the Camera settings for your Non VR Object in your Inspector you just change the Target Eye to "None (Main Display)."

This should work. It did for me. I have the same game in both standard First Person and with the HTC Vive headset. You just Instantiate the Game Object with the First Person Non VR Camera settings instead of the Game Object with the VR Camera Settings when you don't want VR in the game.

Comment: Changing this setting is not sufficient. Behavior does not change.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions,

1. Open **SteamVR_Settings**, which can be done by clicking **Window -> SteamVR Input -> Advanced Settings -> SteamVR Settings**.
   [image]
2. Close the **SteamVR Input** window and Uncheck **Auto Enable VR** in the inspector.
   [image: steamvr settings]
3. Go to **Project Settings -> Player** and uncheck **Virtual Reality Support**.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

my oh my looks like this setting keeps moving.

Using the SteamVR Asset 2.5.0 in Unity 2019.3, the 'Auto Enable VR' setting can be found in the following Scriptable Object:

Assets/SteamVR_Resources/Resources/SteamVR_Settings.asset

Comment: Unchecking this setting is not sufficient. Behavior does not change.

Comment: Did the trick in my project ;)